# How to create a array variable containing the values of another variable in a table?

Tags: mapinfo, mapbasic

I am new to mapbasic and would like to have  an array variable (sac) in order to access it through the "For variable = 1 To n" function. I would like to create a loop that only takes on the value of a variable (var) in a table and loops through all the values in that Table.

```
Include "Mapbasic.def"
Declare Sub Main()

Dim sac(100) As Integer
Dim var As Integer

Sub Main()

Sac(1) = 50
Sac (100) = 1200

For sac = 1 to sac(100)

Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use a temporary 'index' variable to iterate through the position in the array. Something along these lines should work:

```
Include "Mapbasic.def"
Declare Sub Main()

Dim sac(100) As Integer
Dim var As Integer

Sub Main()
    Sac(1) = 50
    Sac(100) = 1200

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To UBound(sac)
        var = sac(i)
    Next

End Sub
```

Edit: try this:

Include "Mapbasic.def"
    Declare Sub Main()

```
Dim sac(100) As Integer
Dim var As Integer

Sub Main()
    Dim iNumberRows As Integer
    iNumberRows = TableInfo( "YOUR_TABLE", TAB_INFO_NROWS )
    ReDim sac(iNumberRows)

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To UBound(sac)
        Fetch Rec i From YOUR_TABLE
        sac(i) = YOUR_TABLE.var
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Actually, what I meant is that I cannot give a value to var as it is already given (predetermined) from a specific table. At the sametime I would like to loop thru those various var values from the table. I am not sure if creating an array named sac would resolve my issue ?

Comment: Try my revised code now.

Comment: This might be unsafe - especially if you have deleted records in your table. Fetching a deleted record will raise an error in your application. Just so you know and take your precautions